# can't connect to bluetooth device after updating to new version

Tags: networking, bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

i have recently updated ubuntu version
this is my current versions
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 23.10
Release:  23.10
Codename:  mantic
the issue for me rn is that i cant connect to my bluetooth devices like speakers and headsets, not sure of the reason, i tried to uninstall bluetooth drivers and reinstall (by help of google) still it didn't help
tried to check bluetooth service status, it's all working and fine, i can turn on bluetooth, but when i try to connect to a device listed on available devices it loads for 10 sec and doesn't really connect to the device, any specific reason or fix for this issue?
i tried this to get active devices

```
user@me:~$ sudo hcitool scan
<mac addr>  boAt Stone 260
user@me:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect <mac addr>
Device <mac addr>. not available
```

mac addr was same still it couldn't connect yes i am sure the device is also set to pair, also this issue i just started facing since today after updating systems

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

If it helps, yo can look at my question:

[Ubuntu can't connect a bluetooth headphones after a update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508364/ubuntu-cant-connect-a-bluetooth-headphones-after-a-update)

To sum up: booting the system into an old linux kernel fixed the problem for me.
In the Grub  menu,at booting, choose "advanced options" and try to pick an older kernel version to boot. It worked for me.
If it worked for you, yo can change the /etc/default/grub file in order to make this old kernel as the default kernel when your computer boots (you can search how to do it).

Regards