# Ubuntu can't connect a bluetooth headphones after a update

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, 23.10, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

I recently updated my laptop to **Ubuntu 23.10 (with kernel 6.5.0-26-generic).**

I have a bluetooth headphones that used to connect perfectly to my laptop without any problems, but since I update my system to the new kernel, I can't connect my bluetooth headphones to the computer. It just keeps trying to connect infinitely and can't.

The headphones connect well with other devices, so the problem comes from the update. What could be happening? How do I solve it?

running lsusb command:
....
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
....

Thanks for the support

Comment: Can you use Grub menu, advanced options to boot into older kernel?

Comment: Edit question to include results from terminal for `dpkg -l | grep 6.5.0-26-generic`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with kernel 6.5.0.21, (booting into this old kernel via GRUB Advanced options).

```
$ dpkg -l | grep 6.5.0-26-generic:  
pi  linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic                   6.5.0-26.26                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pi  linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic                     6.5.0-26.26                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
pi  linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic                   6.5.0-26.26                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pi  linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic             6.5.0-26.26                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```